# Calculate Norton's current's argument in AB

Tags: phasor, norton

[image]

AC1 = 5 arg (53°) A, Zd = 60 arg (45°) Ω, Z1 = 40 arg (37°) Ω, Z2 = 60 arg (37°) Ω

What is the argument of Norton's current in the terminals AB?

I was wondering how Im supposed to do Norton's equivelent here, I know Im supposed to leave the circuit open where the current source AC1 is but Im lost on where to start calculating Norton's Z afterwards because the circuit is open between Zd and Z1.

Comment: please provide an attempt at a solution. Also provide the source for the image.

Comment: At least to an American (and one who knows something about circuits): I don't know what Norton's current IS (and how it can be in a pair of terminals that are not connected??) And by argument I think you mean phase??

Comment: AB is any circuit a person could want to plug into those terminals, Norton's current would be the current that would go through any circuit plugged into AB. It's not as AB are not connected but We don't know what is in between them. Yes the phase my appologies